# How to find the missing letters of an ascending order arranged word in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

The problem statement is as follows:

A word (list) is arranged in ascending order. Now some of the letters of the word are masked while some letters are visible. My task is to make a list of all the letters which aren't present in the word such that the ascending order condition of the word is maintained.

To give an example: consider the word = `['*', '*', 'd', '*', '*', 'm']`. Now here the first two blanks can only have letters - a, b or c while the two blanks towards the end can take letters - e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l

The existing letters in the word can't be used to fill the blanks. To solve this I have tried to write the following code, however there's some glitch. Some help would be great!

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
word = ['*', '*', 'd', '*', '*', 'm']

if '*' not in word:
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] != '*':
            for j in range(len(word)):
                if word[j] == '*' :
                    if j< i:       #means the left part of the word is empty
                        for a in letters:
                            if a < word[i]:
                                new_left_letters.append(a)
                    elif j>i:         #means the right part of the word is empty
                        for a in letters:
                            if a > word[i]:
                                new_right_letters.append(a)
                        
    final_letters = new_left_letters + new_right_letters 

else:
    final_letters = letters     #means the entire letter is empty

print(final_letters)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if '*' not in word:` be `if '*' in word:`?

Comment: @Barmar no, that line is correct because I am starting off by checking if there's even any single letter in the masked word. If there's no letter in the masked word, then I am directing jumping to the last else condition.

Comment: That doesn't tell you if there's a litterl in the masked word. It tells you if there's a mask in the word. And if there's a mask, you jump to the `else:` block which doesn't replace them.

Comment: Anyway, here's the algorithm. Get the slice of of letters between the letters around `*`, and the count of `*`. Then use `itertools.combinations(slice, count)` to get all the possible replacements.

Comment: @Barmar Two requests from me: 1. could you write the code what you suggested ? 2. Also is it possible to write a simple code without using such libraries such as itertools?

Comment: itertools is a module from the standard library. You don't need any other library to use itertools.

Comment: What exactly should be the output of the program in the given example?

Comment: @Barmar I have to submit an entire model the next day. That's the reason I asked. I unfortunately don't have the luxury of time by my side, I already learned basics of python in 2 days time, built an entire code consisting of multiple modules and I had to learn about multiple other technical stuff other than coding. Haven't slept in the past two days. Hence I have reached my break down point and not able to think through this.

Comment: See [under what circumstances may I add urgent to my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: You haven't answered the comment that asked for the expected output for this particular example.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Hi ! the output should be a list of all letters which aren't present in the word and which fit the conditions as follows : 1. suggested letters can't be repeated 2. the letters should follow the ascending order, so for e.g. before the letter d in the above e.g., there are three slots which can be filled by a,b, or c only

Comment: Can you *show* the expected output instead of *describing* it?

Comment: Rahul, when asked for clarification it's always better to  edit your question than to elaborate in comments. Readers will lose interest if they have to read all the comments as well as your question to try to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: *"the output should be a list of all letters"*: how does that list fulfil the requirements? How would you know from such a list which letters are the ones that can come before the "d" and which are those that can come after the "d" (in the example)? Please edit your question and provide the *literal* output expected for the example case (in Python format).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say a 'gap' is one or more consecutive masked letters, bounded on both ends by either an unmasked letter or one of the ends of the input array.

We can solve our gaps independently, then multiply them to get the final results.

Say we're solving a gap of length r which has k >= r letters to choose from (if k < r then there's no solution). The count of possible solutions is choose(r, k).

To enumerate these, use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

combinations('valid_letters', r)

E.g.,

```
combinations('ABCD', 2) = AB AC AD BC BD CD
```

Once you've done this for each gap, you need to combine every valid solution for gap 1 with every valid solution for gap 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I attacked this question!

```
master_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
word_letters = ['*', '*', 'd', '*', '*', 'm']

alphabets = []

previous_letter_index = 0 # will hold the index of the last resolved letter

def find_next_letter(word_letter, word_letters):
    found_wl = False
    for i in range(len(word_letters)):
        if found_wl and word_letters[i] != '*':
            return word_letters[i]
        elif word_letters[i] == word_letter:
            found_wl = True
    return -1

for i, word_letter in enumerate(word_letters):
    if word_letter != '*':
        # find the available letters for the * slots prior to this letter
        print(f"Found letter: {word_letter}")
        master_letter_index = master_letters.index(word_letter)
        print(f"Master index: {master_letter_index}")
        available_letters = master_letters[previous_letter_index:master_letter_index]
        print(f"Available letters: {available_letters}")

        # If there is another letter in the word, restrict the available letters.
        next_letter = find_next_letter(word_letter, word_letters)
        if previous_letter_index != 0 and next_letter != -1:
            for _ in range(previous_letter_index, i):
               alphabets.append(available_letters[:available_letters.index(next_letter)])
        else:
            for _ in range(previous_letter_index, i):
                alphabets.append(tuple(available_letters))

        previous_letter_index = master_letter_index

print(sorted(list(set(alphabets)), key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

Comment: Hi Matt! Thanks for the solution, no this isn't a homework assignment. Your solution is generating duplicate values. [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']]

Comment: Hey. Apart from the duplication, there's some mistake in your code. It's giving values which are already present before (this is not allowed as mentioned in the problem statement.  For e.g. for the word : ['a', '*', 'd', '*', 'm', ''], between a and d, only letters b & c are possible while your code is giving solution as :   
Found letter: d
Master index: 3
Available letters: ['a', 'b', 'c']

Comment: @Rahul Hi! The alphabets are generated for each * character. If you want, you can remove the duplicates using a `Set` but you will have to convert each alphabet to a tuple before doing so, as Lists are not hashable. As for 'd' and 'm' *shrug emoji* Good luck! Hope this is a good starting point.